# Why one tweet can have many IDs?

Tags: twitter

When searching tweets by the Twitter API, I got many tweets in the response with different IDs, but representing the same tweet. Example of IDs:

```
898174127525199872
898164436929716224
898163389104406529
898162871690944513
898163196938248193
```

You can see any of this tweets by URL: `twitter.com/Triangle_Global/status/<id>` - replacing `<id>` with a number. All this URLs redirect to the same address, the page with tweet `897793867822411776`. Moreover, this ID was not returned in the search query.

Why one tweet has many IDs? Is it possible to construct a query that returns only "original" tweets, without such "duplicate" ids?

Answer (score 1):

All these tweets that you reference are retweets of `897793867822411776`. You can see this by looking at the `retweeted_status` field.

You didn't say which API endpoint you are using. If you are using `search/tweets` there is no way to return only "original" tweets. What you can do is throw out any tweets that has the `retweeted_status` field present. If the tweet is not a retweet it will not contain this field.